# Assistance in sample size calculation using paired-t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I am performing a prospective interventional study that is one arm. I need to calculate the sample size.

The study is about the impact of a specific intervention on systolic blood pressure. No studies have been done before on this topic, so I determined the minimally required decrease in systolic blood pressure to result in clinically meaningful impact on my patients.

However, most calculators require me to enter the standard deviation. I don't have standard deviation. How to assume/calculate it?

Also, when I enter any standard deviation and I get the results, it tells, let's say, 50 pairs are required. Does this mean that we need 50 patients since each patient will be measured twice?

Finally, why do we assume normally distributed data, and, hence, calculate based on paired-test? How do we now that the data will be normal?

Comment: Welcome to cv, yusefsoliman! You have a lot of questions - yeah, you have to make a lot of assumptions before you can calculate anything. One thing that you need in advance if you want to calculate sample size is the magnitude of the difference that you want to be able to detect in comparison to the standard deviation. You should look at outcomes from similar studies, they can give you an idea. Did you check out the [questions that we have here on cv already about that topic](power paired t test answers:1)?

Comment: Sorry, the link in my previous comment did not work out, [here it is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+paired+t+test+answers%3A1)